# The collection type 'Microsoft.Graph.IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage' on 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceUsersCollectionResponse.Value' is not supported

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get list of Azure AD B2C users based on code sample provided [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#user-management-microsoft-graph-operations).

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Which is loading users as expected when I try with .Net core console application or .Net core web application. But I need to load users in .net core class library project. (Azure function project to be specific). But same code in .net core class library throws below expection while fetching user.

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: MainFunction. System.Text.Json: The collection type 'Microsoft.Graph.IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage' on 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceUsersCollectionResponse.Value' is not supported.

I could not figure out any document or cause related to this error. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same problem today but I updated all NuGet packages to latest pre-release versions and it's now working.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I had the same error, although I already had the latest pre-release packages installed.

I discovered that I recently explicitely installed the "**Microsoft.Graph.Core**" NuGet package.

Usually, this package is implicitely installed by "Microsoft.Graph.Auth" and "Microsoft.Graph.Beta".

I removed the explicitely installed NuGet package "Microsoft.Graph.Core" and then did the following call in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2019:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

After a rebuld of my project, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough, I ran into this problem when I upgraded the following packages:

1. `Microsoft.Graph`
2. `Microsoft.Graph.Core`

Initially, I was not sure why this error would have occurred.

To resolve it, I first tried Uwe Kleim's solution and ran `Update-Package -Reinstall`. That did not work, but it did reinstall the package, so it may have helped (keep reading).

Next, I reverted the upgrade on the packages. I reverted `Microsoft.Graph` first and then did a rebuild. The problem still existed. So, I reverted the upgrade on `Microsoft.Graph.Core` and the problem went away. I then upgraded `Microsoft.Graph` and then did a rebuild. This time, the error went away AND when I went to upgrade `Microsoft.Graph.Core`, it was not available to be upgraded. So, it must have been upgraded with `Microsoft.Graph`.

My best bet as to the root cause: I upgraded the packages in the wrong order and Visual Studio did not like that.