# ms-graph API with C#; how to fix this driveitem error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the following error, could someone please help me understand this error or how to fix it? It's a external error so I am a bit of out depth.

*System.NotSupportedException: 'The collection type 'Microsoft.Graph.IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage' on 'Microsoft.Graph.DriveItem.Children' is not supported.'*

```cs
public static async Task CopyFileToTeams(string site_id, string item_id, string lcl_itempath)
{
    var driveItem = new DriveItem
    {
        Name = lcl_itempath
    };

    await graphClient.Groups[site_id]
        .Drive.Items[ item_id ]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync( driveItem );
}
```

Comment: Are you still facing the issue here? Have you tried debugging it using breakpoints in visual studio?

Comment: I believe there is an issue with my VS2019 it fails to recognize the presence of .net 4 and upwards, I have tried installing them to no avail. I am now learning how to setup C# projects in vscode. I have more experience with it and I actually understand the debugger. So, will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question I found on the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294508/the-collection-type-microsoft-graph-igraphserviceuserscollectionpage-on-micro).
The gist of it is DO NOT INSTALL "Microsoft.Graph.Core". They are implicitly installed by "Microsoft.Graph.Auth" and "Microsoft.Graph.Beta". So I uninstalled and reinstalled all the "Microsoft.Graph" packages from nuget except for the "Microsoft.Graph.Core". Now it finally works...