# Could not get user's information using Microsoft Graph with Application Permissions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph SDK with .Net to retrieve a specific user's information such as email address, first name, and last name.

I've created an applications under the Azure B2C and give it the following permissions:
[image]

Then, using a console app I've created a new GraphServiceClient and the the following code to retrieve a specific user:

```
Microsoft.Graph.User graphUser = await MicrosoftGraph.Users[id].Request().GetAsync();
```

It's returning the right user, but I couldn't retrieve any of the information I needed such as email address.

How can I ask the API the retrieve these info for me and not and empty user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` query parameter in your code to return the set of user information

**For Example,**

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Select("displayName,Mail")
    .GetAsync();
```

Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter) to learn more.

Comment: Hi @Elie, can you please share screen shots or output where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MS graph api for **Azure B2C**. B2C currently cannot call **MS Graph API**. You must use [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#build-user-crud-operations-by-using-the-graph-api) to manage users in Azure AD B2C directory.

please see:[here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/526) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072756/microsoft-graph-rest-api-v1-0-access-to-b2c-tenant-users).

Comment: Thank you for that, but it seems that you can use MS Graph API for B2C as of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#build-user-crud-operations-by-using-the-graph-api).

I did use it, and it returned users as requested, the issue is that I got only the display name of the users. Couldn't get their emails, given names, ...

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294508/the-collection-type-microsoft-graph-igraphserviceuserscollectionpage-on-micro).

It seems that the full functionalities for B2C are only available using Microsoft Graph Beta.